# Nuxt-Axios post with header and body

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

Where i'm mistake,

when i make post request in some html file like that.

```
<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://some.com/some/',
        headers: {"token": "aspsi39393dndj383", "Content-Type": "application/json"},
        data: {
          page: 1
        }
      });
    </script>
</body>
```

everything work well, it's return me 200 ok status but when i try it in nuxt-axios via vuex store like:

```
await this.$axios.post('http://some.com/some/', {headers: {"token": "aspsi39393dndj383", "Content-Type": "application/json"},
                    data: {
                      page: 1
                    }}).then(response => {
                        // If request is good...
                        console.log(response.data);
                      })
                      .catch((error) => {
                        console.log('error 3 ' + error);
                      });
```

it's return me cors and internal server errors.

Comment: instead of `this.$axios.post` use `this.$axios.$post`